# ValidateRequest - getting error and display on current page

Tags: asp.net, custom-errors, validate-request, custom-error-handling

I have an asp.net application and I've realized, that if I set `ValidateRequest` to `false`, always a standard error page is displayed.

I've heard, that you can display a custom error page.

But I need to know **if I can catch the error and display it** (after postback) **on the current page**, that is being displayed.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the following article:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2003/07/07/9791.aspx

The last point of the article (**Overriding the OnError Method**), describes how to display an error on the current page.

The `OnError` method has to be overwritten and the `error StatusCode` has to be set to 200.

```
protected override void OnError(EventArgs e)
{
  System.Exception oops = Server.GetLastError();

  if(oops.GetBaseException() is System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException )
  {
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(false);
    Response.Write(oops.ToString());
    Response.StatusCode = 200;
    Response.End();        
  }       
}
```